# Firebase Firestore - how to retrieve an array field from a specific document and use those array values to map documents

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, mapping

I have user and group collections. Under the user collection, each document id is a user UID and each user document has an array field "userGroups" which contains the groups that user belongs to and those groups are the group's document ID under group collection.

I have been able to retrieve the userGroups array for the current user which i stored in groupRef (see code below). What I'm trying to do now is to map those array values into groups collection and retrieve only those documents that are in the groupRef. (Basically the goal is to just show in the UI the groups that the current user is a member of)

[user collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8456.png)
[group collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWrAO.png)

```
const [groupsList, setGroupList] = useState([]);
const [groupRef, setGroupRef] = useState([]);
const [track, setTrack] = useState('')

const handleSubmit = () => {
    setTrack('start')
    fire.firestore().collection('users').doc(fire.auth().currentUser.uid).get().then((value) => {
        console.log("userGroups  " + value.data().userGroups)   // this returns an object
        setGroupRef([value.data().userGroups])
    })
} 

useEffect(() => {
    handleSubmit()
}, [track])

console.log("sample list   " + groupRef)
```

---

```
    fire.firestore().collection('groups').onSnapshot(snapshot => (
        setGroupList(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))
    ))
```

^ this returns all the documents under groups collection. any ideas how i can retrieve only those that the current user is a member of? any help would be much appreciated. (ive been stuck on this for a long time. im also new to firebase.)

Comment: You have a groupMembers field in the group document.  Are you trying to do an array-contains query to look for documents where that user is present in the array? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership

Comment: @DougStevenson hey doug! im trying to retrieve the documents where that user is part of the groupMembers field yes. i think my code above gives me the groups of which the current user is part of. would using array-contains shorter and more efficient?

Comment: could you show me, in relation to my code, how the array-contains query would work?

Comment: the logic i have formed atm is to get the userGroups for the current user, then use those data to query in groups collection since i have the groups document ID saved but im stuck on it atm

Comment: i got it working using array-contains!         fire.firestore().collection('groups').where("groupMembers", "array-contains", fire.auth().currentUser.uid).onSnapshot(snapshot => (
            setGroupList(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))
        ))

Comment: Great! Feel free to answer your own question, then.

Answer (score 0):

@DougStevenson directed me to the right path of using **array-contains** which is a helper function on querying/getting data. the code below is the answer to my problem. this way is shorter and more efficient than the work i came up with.

```
fire.firestore().collection('groups').where("groupMembers", "array-contains", fire.auth().currentUser.uid).onSnapshot(snapshot => ( setGroupList(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))
))
```